# How to prove a morphism an identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory

In category theory, the definition of identity morphism/arrow is part of the definition of a category.

To build a category, it must satisfy the following statement:

> For every object x, there exists a morphism 1x : x → x called the identity morphism for x, such that for every morphism f : a → b, we have 1b ∘ f = f = f ∘ 1a.

But this statement says that "To become a category, what must be satisfied", it does not explicit say that "To become a identity morphism, what must be satisfied".

So I have something confusion about "How to prove a morphism is identity in some category".

For example:

Suppose I have a category C (there may be a lot of objects and morphisms in it), I pick a object (called it A) and there is a morphism to itself called pre-idA : A->A, I want to prove this morphism is a identity morphism on A.

How should we prove it?

There are many options for me, but I'm not sure which is correct ?

Method1:

To prove pre-idA is a identity, we must prove that

(1)∀X∈C.∀f : X->A. pre-idA ∘ f = f holds, and

(2)∀X∈C.∀f : A->X. f ∘ pre-idA = f holds

Both (1) and (2) must be satisfied.

Method2:

To prove pre-idA is a identity, we must prove that

(1) ∀X∈C.∀f : X->A. pre-idA ∘ f = f holds, or

(2) ∀X∈C.∀f : A->X. f ∘ pre-idA = f holds

One of (1) and (2) be satisfied is enough.

Intuitively, if we using Method1 to prove, then the pre-idA must be identity.
But does Method1 require too strong condition?

If the Method2 is wrong, can you give an example of a category to show that such morphism are not actually identity?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show either condition to be true, then the morphism in question is certainly the identity. However, both methods are an overkill. Note that if
$$
\forall f \in \operatorname{Hom}_C(A, A): \operatorname{preid_A} \circ f = f.
$$
then in particular,
$$
\operatorname{preid_A} = \operatorname{preid_A} \circ \operatorname{id_A} = \operatorname{id_A}.
$$

So it's sufficient to verify one direction. The same holds for the second method you have. Just take $X = A$.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the mean about "If you show either condition to be true" ? (Sorry, maybe my understanding of English is somewhat ambiguous)

Comment: It's correct, though it *presumes* that $C$ is already a category, whereas one would want to use it to prove existence of identity morphisms in order to show that $C$ is a category.

Comment: OK, I think I have understood what you mean. You means that both Method1 and Method2 are correct, but overkill. You mentioned the 3rd method, it is very surprise for me! But it is correct indeed. I re-elaborate as follows: "To prove preid-A is a identity, we just need to prove that ∀f : A->A. preid-A ∘ f = f" that is all enough. This because idA must be existed on A, it is also a "f", so "preid-A ∘ idA = idA". And also, idA is an identity, it satisify identity property, using this identity property, we got "preidA ∘ idA = preid-A". Therefore "preid-A = idA". Thanks!

Comment: @Berci Indeed. The question assumes $C$ is already a category with identity morphisms.

Comment: @chansey you got it right.

Comment: In fact there are still some overkill by the 3rd method. To prove preid-A is a identity, we just need to prove that preid-A ∘ idA = idA.